# No Video playback on iOS chrome 71 with A-Frame

Tags: ios, google-chrome, aframe

I am having an issue with video playback only on iPhone  chrome version 71 (iOS version 12). I have A-Frame that renders the video sphere with three.js under the hood. The video doesn’t play at all and all I see is a thumbnail. The same video plays all good with no console errors in safari, Mac/windows chrome and Firefox. Any ideas will help me get to a valid solution. Thank you!

Comment: What about Safari? Can you share link to reproduce?

Comment: Safari works all good. Is there an email that I can send the link to?

Comment: https://glitch.com/~aframe works well

Comment: Your example is a link to https://samsungvr.com/view/SYDOayGfmz_ That's not an A-Frame application

Comment: Ok...Looks like you are more interested in a simple A-Frame example. I have a codepen that might be helpful : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vvqwKa. This works on mac/iphone safari, chrome and FF for ubuntu, windows. Only iPhone chrome 71 does not work and shows just a blank screen.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a setup to remote debug iPhone on chrome.